# Shouldnt a lock on class block threads from all class instances

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
public class Fern extends Thread
{
    private String x = "varun"; 

    public void run()
    {
         synchronized(Fern.class){

        System.out.println(x);
        try {
            sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        x = "Anku";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {
        Fern f = new Fern();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Fern());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Fern());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output is:
varun
varun

Since the block has been synchronized on Fern.class, only one thread should be allowed to enter the block at a time irrespective of which instance it belongs to since there is only one lock for the class for all instances. If I replace new Fern() in the Thread constructor with a single Fern object, the output is:
varun
Anku.
The behaviour is what would have been had I synchronized on(this).
I dont understand why this is happening since I synchronized

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not a `static` variable. Change it to `static`.

> static String x = "varun";

---

**EDIT**:
or pass the *same* object as parameter to `t1` and `t2`.

```
Fern f = new Fern();
Thread t1 = new Thread(f); // pass the same object
Thread t2 = new Thread(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

`x` is an instance variable - in other words, even though only one thread can enter that block at a time, they're looking at different variables. Changing the value of `x` in the first thread doesn't affect the `x` that the second thread is looking at.

In other words, the synchronization is "correct" (if you don't want more than one thread to enter that block *regardless* of instance) but your data access isn't doing what you think it should.

As a side note, I personally prefer locking on references which *only* my class can see.

As *another* side note, it would be better if `Fern` implemented `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread` - you're currently passing one thread to another one's constructor, which doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Thanks guys. x should be static. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` in each instance of the thread is a different one.  Try `private static String x` to use a shared `x` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with synchronization. `x` is an instance variable, so each `Fern` instance has its own copy, initialized to "varun", then printed, then set to "Anku".

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two different `Fern` instances, the fact that one of them changes the value of its `x` field is not seen by the other. (I am guessing, since you don't give the declaration of `x`. To get better answers, post only *complete* code.)